# Get the specific value of filter in Django

Tags: python, django

I know this is common to ask but I wondered if is there's any way to convert the object value to specific value like Integer , The out put of the filtered query is `card_tbl object (1)` but I want to get the specific value of this which is `1`

```
cardId = 1
card_tbl = card_tbl.objects.get(id=cardId)
print(card_tbl)
```

**The Print returns** instead of specific value example. `1`

```
card_tbl object (1)
```

Then my **second question** is there any way to Query the object to another table like this?

```
    cardId = 1
    card_tbls = card_tbl.objects.get(id=cardId)
    cat1 = category1_tbl.objects.get(id=card_tbls)
```

**Models.py**

```
class main_tbl(models.Model):
  category1 = models.ForeignKey(category1_tbl, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
  category2 = models.ForeignKey(category2_tbl, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=1500,blank=True, null=True)
  requested_by = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
  path = models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True, null=True)
  date_requested = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  status = models.IntegerField(max_length=60, default=0, null=True)

class category1_tbl(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
  isactive = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
  created =  models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  path = models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True, null=True)
  modify = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  created_by = models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True, null=True)

class category2_tbl(models.Model):
  category1 = models.ForeignKey(category1_tbl, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
  priority = models.ForeignKey(priority_tbl, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
  isactive = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
  created =  models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  modify = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  created_by = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: card_tbls.columnname will get the value of object that you had filtered.For Example card_tabls.id will get the id of the object

Comment: @Akram thanks for the response I get what you mean but even though I print `card_tabls.id` it returns me an error when matching to another table  since it returns an Object not the specific one, my question is how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use django model `__str__`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#str

> The **str**() method is called whenever you call str() on an object.
> Django uses str(obj) in a number of places. Most notably, to display
> an object in the Django admin site and as the value inserted into a
> template when it displays an object. Thus, you should always return a
> nice, human-readable representation of the model from the **str**()
> method.

Try something like this

```
class YourModel(model.Models):

    your_fields = model.CharField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for response but I'm just newbie here it is bit more complex for me to understand this, I think there's other way which is lot more easier than this, Im stuck with this module

Comment: Can you show your models.py code

Comment: thanks for your response I uploaded my models.py